# Communication between Angular.js controllers and Polymer custom elements

Tags: angularjs, controller, communication, polymer, custom-element

I'm using Angular.js on one of my projects and I want to combine it with Polymer. I have some problems with the comunication between Angular.js controllers and the Polymer custom elements.

What is my problem...

For example I have an AuthService, an AuthController which uses the AuthService to send requests to the backend (Node.js with Express) and a simple login form like this:

```
<form role="form" ng-submit="login()">
    <div>
        <label for="usernameInput">Username: </label>
        <input type="text" name="usernameInput" id="usernameInput" placeholder="Username" ng-model="usernameInput" required>
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="passwordInput">Password: </label>
        <input type="password" name="passwordInput" id="passwordInput" placeholder="Password" ng-model="passwordInput" required>
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="rememberMeInput">Remember me: </label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="rememberMeInput" id="rememberMeInput" ng-model="rememberMeInput">
    </div>

    <input type="submit" name="loginSubmit" value="Log in">
</form>
```

Everiting is working fine in this format but I want to move the form inside a Polymer custom element like this:

```
<polymer-element name="cg-login-form">
    <template>
        <div layout vertical>
            <div class="error hidden">{{ error }}</div>

            <form role="form" layout vertical center>
                <div>
                    <paper-input type="text" floatinglabel label="Username" value="{{ inputData.username }}"></paper-input>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <paper-input type="password" floatinglabel label="Password" value="{{ inputData.password }}"></paper-input>
                </div>

                <div layout horizontal center>
                    <paper-checkbox role="checkbox" checked="{{ inputData.rememberBe }}"></paper-checkbox>
                    <div>Remember me</div>
                </div>

                <paper-button label="Log in" raisedbutton role="button" on-click="??????"></paper-button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </template>

    <script>
        Polymer('cg-login-form', {
            inputData: {
                username: undefined,
                password: undefined,
                rememberMe: false
            }
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

My problem is: How to call the login method of the AuthController on form submit and I want the Polymer element to stay Angular.js independent.

I was thinking to fire a login event with the input data and to listen for this event inside the AuthController. Then the login event handler can call the AuthContoller's login method, but I can't get the sent data with the event.

This is how I'm firing the event inside the:

```
<paper-button label="Log in" raisedbutton role="button" on-click="{{ login }}"></paper-button>

Polymer('cg-login-form', {
    inputData: {...},
    login: function() {
        this.fire('login', { loginData: this.inputData });
    }
});
```

And this is how I'm listening for the login event inside the AuthController:

```
// In this way the detail and the data properties of the event object are undefined
angular.element("#loginForm").on('login', function(event) {
    console.log(event.detail);
    console.log(event.data);
});

// In this way the detail and the data properties of the event object are undefined
$('#loginForm').on('login', function(event) {
    console.log(event.detail);
    console.log(event.data);
});

// In this way the detail property of the event object is set with the sent data
document.getElementById('loginForm').addEventListener('login', function(event) {
    console.log(event.detail);
    console.log(event.data);
});

// In this way the detail property of the event object is set with the sent data
document.querySelector('#loginForm').addEventListener('login', function(event) {
    console.log(event.detail);
    console.log(event.data);
});
```

Why document.getElementById('loginForm').addEventListener() and document.querySelector('#loginForm').addEventListener() works and the other two ways doesn't work?
How can I get the sent data using jQuery or jqLite? I prefer to use them instead of using the html approach.

I will be glad if you tell me a better way for communication between Angular.js controllers and Polymer custom elements instead of events triggering.

Thank you very much and have a nice day

EDIT:
Also I can get the ng-login-form element from the DOM inside the AuthController and pass the AuthController's login method like a callback to some ng-long-form method. Then on form submit the ng-login-form can call the callback with the input data.

This will work too but I don't think that this is a good approach.

Comment: I'm looking into this myself. How to get polymer events into Angular. This actually helped me a lot. Thanks.

As for your question:
angular.element().on as the DOC states, Does not support namespaces, selectors or _eventData_

But I think both through jQuery or angular.element, you're left with a jQuery or a jqLite object. You're trying to '.on()' on that object, and not on the underlying element. Which you're using on the next two tests (that work).
Perhaps only a [0] should suffice?
$('#el')[0].on()
angular.element('#el')[0].on()
?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way

In the paper-input add --  inputValue="{{ valData }}"   --

for example

```
<paper-input label="name" id="name" class="label-input-full"  inputValue="{{ valData }}">
</paper-input>
```

Add in button submit onclick event

for example

```
<paper-button class="btn-check" type="submit" icon="check" core-overlay-toggle on-click="{{fetchDataFromForm}}" >
</paper-button>
```

Finally in the scripts, add the function for send data to angular

For example

```
Polymer('name-element', {
    fetchDataFromForm: function() {
      USER_DATA = this.valData;
      console.log(USER_DATA);

        var scope = angular.element($("#angular-controller")).scope();
        scope.$apply(function(){
            scope.contacto = { varAngular: USER_DATA };    
            console.log(scope.contacto);
            scope.angularFunction();
        });
    }
}
```

In Angular ... usually done

I hope to help you in something

Regards

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This will work, but I want the Polymer element to stay Angular.js independent. This way I will be able to reuse it. For now I'm using document.querySelector('loginForm').addEventListener() but I don't really like to use document.*